# Why do I crash? Dealloc/release + property/retain weirdness

Tags: objective-c

Code in my controller:

```
CalcBorderBlocks *calcBB = [[CalcBorderBlocks alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *blockArray = [calcBB calc:341241133];
[calcBB release]; // Releases calcBB.
```

Code in CalcBorderBlocks.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface CalcBorderBlocks : NSObject {
 @private
  NSMutableArray *blockArray_;
}
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *blockArray;

- (NSMutableArray *)calc:(int)blockID;

@end
```

Code in CalcBorderBlocks.m:

```
#import "CalcBorderBlocks.h"

@implementation CalcBorderBlocks
@synthesize blockArray = blockArray_;

- (id)init {
  self = [super init];
  if (self) {
    blockArray_ = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; // Retain count should be 1
  }
  return self;
}

- (NSMutableArray *)calc:(int)blockID {
// Do stuff
return self.blockArray;
}

- (void)dealloc {
  [blockArray_ release]; // Normal cleanup, yet crashes! Works fine if I comment out this line.
  [super dealloc];
}
```

@end

Comment: I love the title... why do I crash? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're doing anything with `blockArray` after this line:

```
[calcBB release]; // Releases calcBB.
```

Then that's the cause of the crash.

You're releasing `calcBB` which in turn releases `blockArray` in dealloc.

I suspect you need to retain blockArray, process it as required then release it afterwards.

```
CalcBorderBlocks *calcBB = [[CalcBorderBlocks alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *blockArray = [[calcBB calc:341241133] retain];
[calcBB release]; // Releases calcBB.

// Process blockArray as needed

[blockArray release];
```

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
  CalcBorderBlocks *calcBB = [[CalcBorderBlocks alloc] init];
  NSMutableArray *blockArray = [calcBB calc:341241133];
  [calcBB release]; // Releases calcBB.
```

usually means that blockArray is retained but also autoreleased. If you want to keep it alive, you'll have to retain it yourself, otherwise it will be released by the autorelease pool after a while.

Answer (score 0):

Post the backtrace of the crash.  More likely than not, it is because you overreleased something in the array (or the array itself somewhere else.